# How to load javascript function in href using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to crawl some html pages using Nokogiri in my ruby project. In the crawler page, there are some links which I also want to crawl. But the problem is the link's href are in javascript function.

```
<a href="javascript:nextPage('some text','','other text')">Click here</a>
```

How can I load this dynamic pages using Nokogiri?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? We're here to help you fix your code not write it for you. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need the minimal code necessary to duplicate the problem, the minimal input and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Mechanize.

Example usage:

```
require 'mechanize'

mechanize = Mechanize.new

page = mechanize.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')

link = page.link_with(text: 'Random article')

page = link.click

puts page.uri
```

so in this example, just knowing the text element of the link is enough so that should put you on the right track.

Documentation : http://readysteadycode.com/howto-scrape-websites-with-ruby-and-mechanize

Comment: Thank you very much for your response though I was searching the solution with Nokogiri gem, as my whole project is using Nokogiri.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with 'headless' gem with Nokogiri. As there were lot of javascript to load the page, I use this

```
require 'headless'
 headless = Headless.new
 headless.start
 browser = Watir::Browser.start(main_page_url)
 if browser.link(text: "Click here").present?
    browser.link(text: "Click here").click
 end
 sleep(2.0) # delay to account for ajax-calls
 #finally close the browser
 browser.close
```